# Automatizar processo de configuração do IE para emissão de NF-e

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch, ssl

Para emitir nf-e dentro do meu sistema preciso que alguns parâmetros do Internet Explorer estejam devidamente configurados da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

• Marcar as opções de SSL

• Desmarcar as opções de TLS

• Desmarcar Verificar revogação de certificados do servidor*

• Marcar Verificar se há assinatura em programas baixados

• Desmarcar Verificar se há certificados revogados do fornecedor

Porém isso gera um serviço muito manual, pois tenho uma carteira muito grande de clientes, e todo cliente que não consegue emitir uma NF-e é necessário alterar manualmente os parâmetros.

Queria saber uma forma seja por linha de comando, `.bat` ou qualquer outra forma de fazer isso de forma automática, pode ser executando um `.bat`

Comment: Já tentou desenvolver algo?

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar: http://serverfault.com/questions/309714/can-i-change-internet-explorer-security-settings-using-a-script